# function return in R programming language

Tags: r

I need help on returning a value/object from function

```
noReturnKeyword <- function(){
  'noReturnKeyword'
}

justReturnValue <- function(){
  returnValue('returnValue')
}

justReturn <- function(){
  return('justReturn')
}
```

When I invoked these functions: `noReturnKeyword()`, `justReturnValue()`, `justReturn()`, I got output as `[1] "noReturnKeyword"`, `[1] "returnValue"`,  `[1] "justReturn"` respectively.

My question is, even though I have not used `returnValue` or `return` keywords  explicitly in `noReturnKeyword()` I got the output (I mean the value returned by the function).

So what is the difference in these function `noReturnKeyword()`, `justReturnValue()`, `justReturn()`

What is the difference in these words `returnValue('')` , `return('')`?  are these one and the same?

When to go for `returnValue('')` and `return('')` in R functions ?

Comment: You don't need to explicitly specify the return in `R`.  It will return the last line

Comment: Never used returnValue, but return and no return are one and the same

Comment: when i used returnValue it worked as same as return and no return, so when to go for returnValue.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `return` is the explicite way to exit a function and set the value that shall be returned. The advantage is that you can use it anywhere in your function.
2. If there is no explicit return statement R will return the value of the last evaluated expression
3. `returnValue`is only defined in a debugging context. The manual states:

> the experimental returnValue() function may be called to obtain the
>   value about to be returned by the function. Calling this function in
>   other circumstances will give undefined results.

In other words, you shouldn't use that except in the context of `on.exit`. It does not even work when you try this.

```
justReturnValue <- function(){
  returnValue('returnValue')
  2
}
```

This function will return 2, not "returnValue". What happened in your example is nothing more than the second approach. R evaluates the last statement which is `returnValue()` and returns exactly that.

If you use solution 1 or 2 is up to you. I personally prefer the explicit way because I believe it makes the code clearer. But that is more a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 2):

In `R`, according to `?return`

> If the end of a function is reached without calling return, the value of the last evaluated expression is returned.