# Why does b have a value?

Tags: r, assign

Why does b have a value? I think b should be null, because there is no return in function f.

```
f <- function(){
  a <- 10
}

b <- f()

b
# [1] 10
```

Comment: The last line of a function is the return value in R.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [function return in R programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62235755/function-return-in-r-programming-language)

Answer (score 4):

`<-` operator returns assignement invisibly, which allows

```
b <- a <- 1
b
a

> b
[1] 1
> a
[1] 1
```