# When I run this code in R, there is no output at all, even in the global environment area. Why is it so?

Tags: r

##This is the code that I ran in R. I run this and there is no output anywhere at all. I cant figure out why.

```
polarizerset <- function(x){
      fw <- c()
      ps <- c(0,1)
      sw <- sample(x, 1, prob = c(0.5,0.5))
      sp <- sample(ps, 1, prob = c(0.5,0.5))
      if( xor(sw,sp) == FALSE ) {
        fw <- c(fw, as.numeric(!sw), as.numeric(!sw))
      } else {
        fw <- c(fw, NULL, NULL)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please make your code complete (needs a sample call to test it that shows what is the problem) and reproducible (need to use `set.seed` before it since there are random numbers used.  Also provide some description a of what i it is intended to do.  See instructions at top of [tag:r] tag page.

Answer (score 0):

There's a result, but it's returned invisibly due to the `<-` operator:

```
polarizerset <- function(x){
  fw <- c()
  ps <- c(0,1)
  sw <- sample(x, 1, prob = c(0.5,0.5))
  sp <- sample(ps, 1, prob = c(0.5,0.5))
  if( xor(sw,sp) == FALSE ) {
    fw <- c(fw, as.numeric(!sw), as.numeric(!sw))
  } else {
    fw <- c(fw, NULL, NULL)
  }
}

res <- polarizerset(2)
res

[1] 0 0
```

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63950909/13513328) which shows why.
If you want to see the result, just remove the `fw <-` which isn't useful in the function:

```
polarizerset <- function(x){
  fw <- c()
  ps <- c(0,1)
  sw <- sample(x, 1, prob = c(0.5,0.5))
  sp <- sample(ps, 1, prob = c(0.5,0.5))
  if( xor(sw,sp) == FALSE ) {
    c(fw, as.numeric(!sw), as.numeric(!sw))
  } else {
    c(fw, NULL, NULL)
  }
}
polarizerset(2)
[1] 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked :)
But why is this happening? If you can tell :)

Comment: Did you have a look at the link I included?

Comment: Yes I did, thank you for the help! :)